# Google sheets: auto sorting based on color and alphabetic order

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have this list:

```
B  (white background)
A  (white background)
C  (green background)
```

And I would like to make a function where I sort it as follows:

```
C (green background)
A (white background)
B (white background)
```

So this sorting does the following Automatically:

- Sort from A-Z
- Also sort the green background colored cells ABOVE the white colored cells.

Atm I have this: =Sort(B2:B1300,1,TRUE) which only sorts from A-Z. Obviously filters dont work because it changes automatically.
Any idea how to do this? I was thinking of GETCOLOR

Answer (score 0):

found a work around using filters :)
Turned on a-z sorting
and filtering the colors